# In PowerShell, I have to store the AzureStack Powershell module Version value as Variable

Tags: powershell

Get-InstalledModule -name AzureStack -AllVersions | Select-Object Version

Result:

### Version

1.7.2

I want to assign the value 1.7.2 as a variable to validate the Azurestack installed Versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select the Version, it will produce the Major, Minor, Build and Revision. You will need to convert it to string. Have a read through the [ExpandProperty vs Property](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2017/10/02/powershell-expandproperty-vs-property/).

```
PS > Get-InstalledModule -name AzureStack -AllVersions | Select Version
Version
-------
1.7.2

PS > Get-InstalledModule -name AzureStack -AllVersions | Select -ExpandProperty Version
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      7      2      -1  

PS > (Get-InstalledModule -name AzureStack -AllVersions | Select -ExpandProperty Version).Tostring()
1.7.2
```

Alternatively, if you are checking to see if a specific version is installed, you can do do the below.

```
$verReq = New-Object -TypeName Version -ArgumentList 1.7.2 # Or (Read-Host)
Get-InstalledModule -name AzureStack -RequiredVersion $verReq
```

If the version that you are looking for doesn't exist, you will get an `No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names` message.